# website and blog - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web, feedback

I have website which require:

1. landing page
2. blog

I'm considering 2 alternative, and I would love to get feedback:

1. Landing page + blog -> in wordpress
2. Landing page in amazon s3 (only static files) and the blog in wordpress

Would would you recommend?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 0):

That second options sounds really really weird. It is very easy to make a frontpage in wordpress, so that would definitely be my first choice.

Let me know if you have a hard time imagining how to make a frontpage in wordpress.

I'm also curious on why you are considering the other option?

Comment: I thought about separating since I want the website landing page to be accessible even if the blog system is down / in maintenance mode. I also wanted to use amazon capabilities to make sure it has 100% uptime and that is replicated across their CDN server. What do you think?

Comment: AWS is not up all the time, as the past few months have shown. :p

Comment: I think it's wayyyy too much for getting 0.0000001% more uptime. Generally, I don't think it's the best idea. You are adding a lot of complexity and you're not really gaining anything.